# Load pdf file in webbrowser control but disable context menu

Tags: .net, pdf, webbrowser-control, windows

In my windows application I can load pdf file in my webbrowser control. But it also displaying context menu and toolbar buttons.

I want to disable right click and the toolbar buttons for pdf file in webbrowser control.

Answer (score 0):

You can install awesomium and then add it into your application use that as your new web browser you can then add a webcontextmenu and make it so the new awesomium web browser can load pdf's and done.

Comment: Can I make the pdf readonly so that users can only see it but not be able to save or print the pdf

Comment: You can't save it by default or print it. It only does what you add to it. I can help you with the code if you need me too just reply back.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but now I am using devexpress :)